# Weird XML formation after Android studio was updated to 3.3. How to get android style formation of xml back?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio-3.3

I've updated my Android Studio to 3.3 version and after it when I drag some new view from pallet it makes its XML very weird, with wrong spaces and two-three attributes `android:blabla` in the same line. When I make hotkey command + shift + L it turn all code in that style with wrong spaces. How to fix it?

```
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/buttonLiteVersion"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:onClick="onLiteVersion"
      android:text="@string/lite_version_name"
      style="@style/MainMenuButton"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>
  <Button
          android:text="Button"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

The upper is **before update**, the lower is **after update**

[image: My settings for editor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If command + shift + L (on pc its Ctrl+Alt+L - Reformat Code) doesn't work for you try to change your settings:

```
 Settings->Editor->Code Style->XML->Android->Layout Files->Wrap Attributes
```

Comment: Am, it didn't turn out your way but I checked Use custom formatting settings and yes, it seems better. Still wrong spaces though

Comment: So the problem was with the settings?

Comment: Seems like. I guess they somehow were ruined after an update. I still can't figure out how to reduce the number of spaces before each android:blabla attribute. Do you know how?

Comment: maybe under   Settings->Editor->Code Style->XML->Android->Layout Files->tabs and indents try to change the size of the spacing there to 4, if that won't work try to play with your other tab

Comment: Yes, it helped! Code Style->XML->Tabs and Indents->Continuation indent in my case was set to 8, so I changed to 4 and now it looks perfect! Thanks!

Comment: great, glad to help.